# SQL Query: 1 Employee Position/Post as 2 results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of employees in their current post/position with their start date in the position and their employment start date.

I need a query to generate current position as one result and if the start date of the position does not match start date of employment show a historic position as a second result.

Data

```
[Employee Number]   Position    [Start Date]    [Employment Start Date]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
12345               Admin       01/01/2017      01/01/2016
```

Output

```
[Employee Number]   Position    [Start Date]    [End Date]
-----------------------------------------------------------
12345               Admin       01/01/2017      NULL
12345               Historic    01/01/2016      31/12/2017
```

Comment: From the square braces, I'm guessing SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
       [Employee Number],
       [Position],
       [Start Date],
       NULL AS [End Date]
FROM 
      TABLE_NAME

UNION ALL

SELECT 
       [Employee Number],
       'Historic' AS [Position],
       [Employment Start Date] AS [Start Date],
       DATEADD( DAY,-1,[Start Date] ) AS [End Date]
FROM 
      TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
      [Start Date] <> [Employment Start Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`:

```
select employee_number, position, start_date, cast(null as date) end_date
from data
union all
select employee_number, position, employment_start_date, dateadd(day, -1, start_date)
from data
where employment_start_date < start_date;
```

Comment: Thank's for your response Gordon. I've got the data as above, with the end date, however, my issue is outputting the data over 2 lines, current post and historic post. Sorry if the description wasn't clear (first post...)

Answer (score 0):

```
            WITH table1 AS (
                SELECT * FROM (
                    VALUES
                        ('12345', 'Admin','2017-01-01','2016-01-01')

                    ) AS a (EmployeeNumber, position,StartDate,EmploymentStartDate)
            )

            select EmployeeNumber, position,StartDate, CASE WHEN StartDate!=EmploymentStartDate THEN NULL ELSE EmploymentStartDate END AS EndDate  from table1
            union
            Select EmployeeNumber,'Historic',EmploymentStartDate as StartDate,DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(yy,1,StartDate)) AS EndDate
            From table1 where StartDate!=EmploymentStartDate
```